# Generalization of Brouwer’s fixed-point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

Perhaps the most widely known version of Brouwer’s famous fixed-point theorem reads as follows:

> For any $n\in\mathbb N$, let $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be a compact (with respect to the Euclidean topology), non-empty, convex set. If $f:A\to A$ is a continuous function, then there is some $x^{\star}\in A$ such that $f(x^{\star})=x^{\star}$.

What I am wondering about is whether the requirement “**convex**” can be weakened to “**connected**.” Intuitively, I believe the proof goes through via a homeomorphism argument, but since I have not seen the weakened version as an explicit theorem, I am seeking confirmation.

Comment: Convex can be weakened to "Contractible and triangulable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, no. Consider a nontrivial rotation of $S^1\subset \mathbb R^2$. Even simply connected doesn't do the job, consider the antipodal map on $S^{n-1}\subset \mathbb R^n$, $n>2$. Convex can be weakened to "a set that is a retract of a convex set," which includes a lot of more general subsets on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Wow, I can’t believe I haven’t thought of this easy counterexample. Thank you very much. I will accept your answer as soon as the time limit on it expires. What I failed to realize is that there exist connected Euclidean sets that are _not_ homeomorphic to any convex set.